# Multiplication Operator on $L^2( \mathbb{R})$ is not Compact

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Let $H=L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we define the multiplication operator with a function $h\in H$, ($0\leq h)$ and $||h||_1>0$
.
We have $$T_h:  H \rightarrow H, T_h(f)=h.f$$

Note that $T$ is bounded linear operator.

I want to prove that $T_h$ is not a compact operator.
So If we suppose that $T_h$ is compact, I need to prove for example that the spectral set is non countable. But I can't find a good start.

Comment: You should probably state something about $h$. It's not true that multiplication by an arbitrary positive function maps $L^2$ into itself.

Comment: You have to assume that $h \in L^{\infty}$ to make $T$ a bounded operator. If $h=0$ a.e. then $T$ is compact so we have  to assume that this is  not the case.

Comment: However, it is somewhat easy to see that the image of $h$ is contained in the spectrum of $T_h$ (simply construct the only possible candidate for an inverse), so if $h$ has uncountable image, it should easily hold. Conversely, if $h$ is a simple function (only has finite image), it should clearly map the unit ball into a sum of balls in $L^2$ of various intervals, so in this case, the operator can't be compact either.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou and / and Mr. Kabo,  I added the condition about the 1-norm of $h$ to be strictly positive.

Comment: Why is multiplication by $L^1$ bounded? It doesn't follow from Cauchy-Schwartz. Did you mean say convolution?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Well I need to prove that the convolution is not compact, so I applied the fourier tranfrm and it gives the multiplication operator, so it's sufficient to prove that the multiplication operator is not compact

Comment: @AnasBOUALII yes, all well and good, but the Fourier transform does not map $L^1$ to $L^1$....it maps to $L^\infty$ as Kabo wanted

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, you are right, and so how to find the non countable subset in the spectrum of $T_h$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So If we suppse that $||h||_1>0$ then we can find the inverse operator for $(T_h-\lambda I) $ for selected $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.
So since, $||h||_1>0$, there exists $\alpha>0$ such that $||h||_1>\alpha$.

Now If we take $\lambda \in [0,\alpha]$ the operator $(T_h-\lambda I)$ will be invertible, and it's inverse will be: $\psi=\frac{I}{h-\lambda}$

And then, we come to the conclusion that $[0,\alpha]\subset \sigma(T_h)$ then $T_h$ is not compact.

Comment: I think you've got the definition of spectrum backwards. $\lambda\in \sigma(T_h)$ if $T_h-\lambda I$ *is not* invertible.

Comment: Also, you cannot deduce from $||h||_1>\alpha,$ that $h-\alpha$ is never $0$.

Comment: yes I agree with both remarks

Answer (score 4):

The idea from MaoWao's answer can also be used to give a direct proof, without any spectral theory.

Since $h$ is not a.e. zero, there is a set $E$ of positive measure on which $h$ is bounded away from zero; say $|h| \ge \epsilon$ on $E$.  As in MaoWao's approach, find a sequence of disjoint sets $E_n \subset E$, each with finite positive measure.  Set $f_n = 1_{E_n} / \sqrt{m(E_n)}$; then the $f_n$ are orthonormal, and in particular they are all in the closed unit ball.  Now verify that the functions $T_h f_n$ are also orthogonal, and $\|T_h f_n\|_{2} \ge \epsilon$.  Conclude from this that $\{T_h f_n\}$ has no convergent subsequence.

Comment: But why such $E_n$ exists?

Comment: It suffices to show that any set $A$ of positive measure contains two disjoint sets of positive finite measure; then iterate.  One way to see the former is to let $A_k = A \cap (k\epsilon, (k+1)\epsilon]$ where $0 < \epsilon < m(A)$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Then $A$ is the countable disjoint union of the $A_k$s.    Since $m(A_k) \le \epsilon$, we see that at least two of the $A_k$ must have positive measure.

Answer (score 2):

If $T$ is compact, then every $\lambda\in \sigma(T)\setminus\{0\}$ is an eigenvalue of finite multiplicity. So it suffices to show that $T_h$ cannot have eigenvalues of finite multiplicity (if $\sigma(T_h)=\{0\}$, then it's easy to see that $h=0$ a.e.).

Look at the eigenvalue equation
$$
hf=T_h f=\lambda f.
$$
For it to have a non-trivial solution, $h$ must equal $\lambda$ on a set $E$ of positive measure. But if this is the case, then one can decompose $E$ into a disjoint union of sets $E_n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, that all have positive measure.  Then $f_n=1_{E_n}$ are orthogonal eigenfunctions to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Thus $\lambda$ has infinite multiplicity.

Note that this decomposition property of the Lebesgue measure is crucial here. There *are* (non-trivial) compact multiplication operators on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.