# Multiplication operator is compact in $L_2[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

> Let $b \in C[O,1]$ and define $(Bf)(x)=b(x)f(x)$ for $f \in L_2[0,1]$ show that $B$ is a compact operator in $L_2[0,1]$ iff $b \equiv 0$

The direction $\Leftarrow )$ is easy to prove because if $b \equiv 0$ then $(Bf)(x)=0$ i.e $Bf$ is the zero functional and that is compact.
In the other way i not sure how use the continuity of b, i try supposing that $b(x)\neq 0$ but i dont see any contradiction.
Any hint or suggestion i will very grateful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiplication Operator on $L^2( \mathbb{R})$ is not Compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406894/multiplication-operator-on-l2-mathbbr-is-not-compact) The idea of the proof there isn't affected by the difference in domain.